# Trying to get user birthday from Facebook but I get nil. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: facebook, swift, ios9

Trying to get user birthday from Facebook but I get nil. What am I doing wrong?

```
  @IBAction func SignInWithFacebookButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if(error != nil)
      {
      let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
        let alertAction = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let doAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        alertAction.addAction(doAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
      }

      self.loadUserFacebookDetails()
    })
  }

  func loadUserFacebookDetails(){

    //Fields read from Facebook.
    let requestParameters = ["fields" : "id, email, name, gender, user_birthday"]
    let userDetails = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: requestParameters)

    userDetails.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error: NSError? ) -> Void in

      if(error != nil){
        let userMessage = error!.localizedDescription
        let alertAction = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let doAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        alertAction.addAction(doAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //Log the user out if there is an error loading user details from facebook.
        PFUser.logOut()
        return
      }

      let userID : String = result["id"] as! String
      print("User id = \(userID)")
      let userFullName : String = result["name"] as! String
      print("User id = \(userFullName)")
      let userEmail : String = result["email"] as! String
      print("User id = \(userEmail)")
      let userGender : String = result["gender"] as! String
      print("User id = \(userGender)")
      let userBirthday : String = result["user_birthday"] as! String
      print("User id = \(userBirthday)")
```

Comment: The user need to give you user_birthday permission. And the field is called birthday and not user_birthday

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user,

"However, people can control who can see the year they were born separately from the month and day so this string can be only the year (YYYY) or the month + day (MM/DD)"

So people can control who can see their birthdays. You may or may not access it via API depending on individual's privacy settings.

Answer (score 0):

`FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: **"/me"**, parameters: ["fields": "name, email, **birthday**....`

Comment: @brimstone please change this lines
`let requestParameters = ["fields" : "id, email, name, gender, **birthday**"]
    let userDetails = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "**/me**", parameters: requestParameters)`

Answer (score -2):

```
                let snapshotValue = requestParameters as? NSDictionary
                let id = snapshotValue?["id"] as? String
                let name = snapshotValue?["name"] as? String
                let email = snapshotValue?["email"] as? String
                let gender = snapshotValue?["gender"] as? String
                let events = snapshotValue?["events"]
                let user_birthday = snapshotValue?["birthday"]
                //let phone = snapshotValue?["phone"] as? String
                let link = snapshotValue?["link"] as? String
                let locale = snapshotValue?["locale"] as? String
                let timezone = snapshotValue?["timezone"]
                let verified = snapshotValue?["verified"]
                let last_name = snapshotValue?["last_name"] as? String
                let first_name = snapshotValue?["first_name"] as? String
                let middle_name = snapshotValue?["middle_name"] as? String
                let picture = snapshotValue?["picture.width(480).height(480)"]
```

Comment: It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct.